# Creating a popup menu with WTemplate in qt

Tags: html, css, wt

I want to create a popup menu with WTemplate in qt. as you know with WTemplate Object in Wt you can get styles to objects in CSS file and don't need to use `addStyleClass` function.

In the below code I create a navigation that has a menu item inside of it. On the other side I create a popup menu but when I want to set this popup menu to menu item I face a problem that I don't know how to do that? Please note that I want to do this just with WTemplate.

```html
<messages>
   <message id="2th_level_logo_template">
      ${POPUP_MENUE_SECTION class="logo_left w3-hide-small w3-bar-item w3-button fa"}
   </message>
   <message id="3th_level_logo_template">
      ${ITEM_POPUP_MENUE class="logo_left"}
   </message>
   <message id="w3_Template">
     ${NAVIGATION_SECTION class="w3-top w3-bar w3-white w3-card"}
   </message>
</messages>
```

```js
    std::unique_ptr<WTemplate> w3_t = make_unique<WTemplate>(WString::tr("w3_Template"));
    std::unique_ptr<WNavigationBar> nav_section = std::make_unique<WNavigationBar>();
    std::unique_ptr<WTemplate> w3_popup_menu_item_logo = make_unique<WTemplate>(WString::tr("2th_level_logo_template"));
    std::unique_ptr<WMenuItem> popup_menu_item = std::make_unique<WMenuItem>(WString::tr("language_nvg"));
    popup_menu_item->setIcon("popup_down_arrow.png");
    std::unique_ptr<WTemplate> w3_popup_menu_logo = make_unique<WTemplate>(WString::tr("3th_level_logo_template"));
    std::unique_ptr<WPopupMenu> popup_menu = std::make_unique<WPopupMenu>();    
    popup_menu->addItem(WString::tr("language_prs"));
    popup_menu->addSeparator();
    popup_menu->addItem(WString::tr("language_eng"));
    w3_popup_menu_logo->bindWidget("ITEM_POPUP_MENUE", move(popup_menu));
    popup_menu_item->setMenu(std::unique_ptr<WPopupMenu>(dynamic_cast<WPopupMenu*>(w3_popup_menu_logo->resolveWidget("ITEM_POPUP_MENUE"))));
    w3_popup_menu_item_logo->bindWidget("POPUP_MENUE_SECTION", move(popup_menu_item));
    nav_section->addWidget(move(w3_popup_menu_item_logo));
    w3_t->bindWidget("NAVIGATION_SECTION", move(nav_section));
```